# How to force YouTube subtitles (closed captions) to appear by default even on iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, iframe, youtube

I own a YouTube video, and I typed up subtitles for it.

I've tagged it with `yt:cc=on`, and I've embedded its iframe onto my website using `cc_load_policy=1&cc=1` (see [docs](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#cc_load_policy)).

When I visit my webpage using Chrome on my desktop, the captions appear by default, which is the desired experience.

**But when I visit the webpage using my iPhone (Chrome on iOS), the captions do *not* appear by default.  How can I make captions appear by default on iOS?**

(They are available if I click the speech bubble icon, but I don't want users to need to know how to do that.)

Comment: I'm also interested to hear about alternatives to YouTube (for hosting video)... if you happen to know of a host who can show captions by default on *all* devices. Thanks.

Comment: 250 views with no upvotes yet? Well, I hope you find the answer somewhere, fellow Googler.  ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sub>Also answered on this [possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55481884/4970442)</sub>

The only way I found is changing the URI from [this pattern](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2s3aJfRr9gE)

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v= + video_id
```

to [this pattern](https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/2s3aJfRr9gE?&hl=es-419)

```
https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/ + video_id + ?hl= lang_code
```

On bash/Linux you can just copy the URI with that structure and then run this command to transform clipboard content (you can make an alias):

```
xclip -selection c -o | echo "$(cat -)?&amp;hl=es-419" | sed "s|youtube.com/watch?v=|youtube-nocookie.com/embed/|1" | xclip -selection c
```

On the example from above I hardcoded Spanish language code. You should use one of the available language codes for that particular video. You can list the available subtitles [ISO 639-1 language codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-1_codes) with [youtube-dl](https://ytdl-org.github.io/youtube-dl/index.html), under the section *Available subtitles for* (won't work for automatic captions):

```
youtube-dl --list-subs "{video_id or url}"
```

The only drawback is that the video will cover the complete screen... which might be good thing to stop procrastinating with related videos :)

Comment: I just tried your answer, and it did not work on iOS, which is what my question is about.

Comment: Please tell me if [this URL](https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/2s3aJfRr9gE?&amp;hl=es-419) doesn't have Spanish subtitles by default. If it doesn't work I'll delete my answer.

Comment: Interesting. That did seem to work. But why does it not work when I change your URL from `es-419` to `en` (which I think should be a valid code according to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-1_codes) or `en-US`?

Comment: And also, what settings do *my* videos need to have for your URL pattern to work to force English captions?

Comment: Maybe is not listed between the available languages. Use `youtube-dl --list-subs` to check this out. I edit my question to provide more info regarding this issue. AFAIK there is no documentation about this feature. It could even stop working at any moment Google decide to.